# In VBA find the max number of times a character appears in a single cell out of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Before I start, I just want to thank every contributor ahead of time. I've only posted one question before, and I was amazed at how quickly I got responses and how much I learned after studying the solution. I'm hoping I will have enough reputation points soon to start upvoting good solutions I find here.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is return one number, and that number is the maximum number of names that appear in a single cell of a worksheet column. Each cell in that column can have any number of names in it. Each name is delimited by a pipe "|", so I count the pipes and then add one to get the number of names in each cell.  For example: Cell value is "Bob | Jon | Larry" = 2pipes +1 = 3 names.

My code below works, but I need to do this on tens of thousands of records. I don't think my solution is a good or efficient way to do it (tell me if I'm wrong). So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to accomplish this, such as without looping through every cell in the range?
2. If there isn't a totally different approach to this, how can I avoid actually printing the name counts in cells in a new column? Could I store these values in an array and calculate the max of the array? (maybe there is already a thread on this topic you could point me to?)

```
Sub charCnt()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Leasing")
Dim vRange As Variant
Dim iCharCnt As Integer
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim iMax As Integer

Const sFindChar As String = "|"

iRows = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'count number of rows

For i = 1 To iRows
     vRange = Cells(i, "O") 'column O has the names
    iCharCnt = Len(vRange) - Len(Replace(vRange, sFindChar, "")) 'find number of | in single cell.
    ws.Cells(i, "W") = iCharCnt 'column W is an empty column I use to store the name counts
Next i

iMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("W:W")) + 1 'return max from column W
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox ("Max number of names in one cell is " & iMax) ' show result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Max Number of Substrings

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub charCount()

    Const cCol As String = "O"
    Const fRow As Long = 1
    Const Delimiter As String = "|"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Leasing")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Cells(fRow, cCol).Resize(lRow - fRow + 1)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(i, 1) = Len(Data(i, 1)) - Len(Replace(Data(i, 1), Delimiter, ""))
    Next i
    Dim iMax As Long: iMax = Application.Max(Data) + 1
    
    MsgBox ("Max number of names in one cell is " & iMax) ' show result

End Sub
```

Comment: The classical approach +:)

Answer (score 3):

**A close-to-formula approach**

Combining worksheet functions `CountA()` and `FilterXML()` allows to get all substring counts separated by the pipe character `|`:

```
Sub CountSubstrings(StartCell As Range, TargetRng As Range)
'Purp.: count items separated by pipes
'Meth.: via worksheetfunction FILTERXML()
'Note:  assumes target in same sheet as StartCell (could be changed easily)

'a) enter formula into entire target range
    Const PATTERN$ = _
        "=IF(LEN($),COUNTA(FILTERXML(""<t><s>""&SUBSTITUTE($,""|"",""</s><s>"")&""</s></t>"",""//s"")),0)"
    TargetRng.Formula2 = Replace(PATTERN, _
        "$", StartCell.Parent.Name & "!" & StartCell.Address(False, False))
'b) optional overwriting of formulae
    'TargetRng = TargetRng.Value
'c) display maximum result
    MsgBox Application.Max(TargetRng)

End Sub
```

*Hint:* You can even shorten code as follows if you want to include the fully qualified workbook + worksheet reference in the formula assignment. Just use the additional argument `External:=True` in `.Address` (resulting e.g. in something like `'[Test.xlsm]Sheet1'!A2`):

```
    TargetRng.Formula2 = Replace(PATTERN, _
        "$", StartCell.Address(False, False, External:=True))
```

**Possible Example call**

```
    With Sheet1
        CountSubstrings .Range("A2"), .Range("D2:D5")
    End With
```

**Further link**

C.f. [JvdV's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) encyclopaedia-like site demonstrating the various possibilities to use [`FilterXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697)

Comment: The creative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant answer by VBasic2008.  I thought I would look at it purely as a coding exercise for myself.  Alternative below provided for interest only.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountMaxNames()
Dim arr1(), i, j, count As Long, tally As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("leasing")

arr1 = ws.Range("O1:O" & ws.Range("O" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
count = 0: tally = 0

For Each i In arr1
    For j = 1 To Len(i)
        If Mid(i, j, 1) = "|" Then count = count + 1
    Next j
        count = count + 1
            If count >= tally Then tally = count
        count = 0
Next i

MsgBox "Maximum number of names in one cell is " & tally

End Sub
```

Comment: Never wave aside simple solution +:)

Comment: Well, despite my answer returning a result in under 1.5 seconds when tested on 500,000 cells - somebody still found a reason to give it a downvote.  SO never ceases to amaze me...

Comment: That's little consolation, but you are not alone :-; @kevin9999

Comment: True :-D have to laugh it off.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky to be interested in Excel. It's a rather forgiving sub-community. You do not want to see what is going on with other popular tags like Python or even better.... Regex. It's why I like SO still, because of Excel enthusiasts. Knowing the difference between upvoting an answer because it's *usefull/interesting* or downvoting because it's *not usefull or plain wrong* is widely misinterpreted.

Comment: @JvdV - wise words indeed :)